# TypeScript gives following error for adding a return type for query in RTK query

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, rtk-query

My code is as below:

```
interface CurriculumDetailsApi {
  curriculum_id: number;
  curriculum_name: string;
  description: string;
  percentage_of_completion: number;
  post_id: string;
  post_type: string;
  topics: Topics[];
}

const apiWithTaggedEndpoints = apiWithTag.injectEndpoints({
  endpoints: builder => ({
    curriculumDetails: builder.query<CurriculumDetailsApi, input>({
      query: payload => ({
        url: `/${payload.postId}/${payload.employeeId}`,
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
      }),
    }),
  }),
  overrideExisting: true,
> });
```

I get an error like this:

```
Type '(payload: Args) => { url: string; method: string; headers: { 'Content-Type': string; }; }' is not assignable to type '(arg: Args) => string'.
  Type '{ url: string; method: string; headers: { 'Content-Type': string; }; }' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)
endpointDefinitions.d.ts(36, 5): The expected type comes from property 'query' which is declared here on type 'Omit<EndpointDefinitionWithQuery<Args, BaseQueryFn<string, unknown, { reason: string; }, { shout?: boolean | undefined; }, { timestamp: number; }>, CurriculumDetailsApi> & { ...; } & { ...; } & QueryExtraOptions<...>, "type"> | Omit<...>'
```

How can I assign a type to the data from the API call?

Comment: Welcome! [Here's how to ask a proper "Where's the bug / Fix my code" question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253788/11107541). Can you please read it and apply what you learn to improve your question? You can also read [ask] for further guidance. Please read [ask] and describe your problem _before_ showing code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here will be in how you have defined your `baseQuery`.

I can see in the error message that your `baseQuery` can **only** accept a `string` argument.  The `query` property on your endpoint returns the arguments for the `baseQuery` of your API.  Since your `baseQuery` only accepts a `string`, you can only return a `string`.  Returning this object gives an error.

> ```
> Type '{ url: string; method: string; headers: { 'Content-Type':
> string; }; }' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)
> ```

[I don't get any errors from this code](https://codesandbox.io/s/rtk-endpoint-types-gspudm?file=/src/api/curriculum.ts) if I am using a standard `fetchBaseQuery` as the `baseQuery` for the API.  That `baseQuery` will accept either a `string` or a `FetchArgs` object, which is what you are returning here.

You must modify your `baseQuery` so that it can accept `string | FetchArgs`.

---

Here are the types for your baseQuery, as shown in your error message:

```
BaseQueryFn<
  string, // Args
  unknown, // Result
  { reason: string; }, // Error
  { shout?: boolean | undefined; }, // DefinitionExtraOptions
  { timestamp: number; } // Meta
>
```

The first generic, `Args`, is the one which matters here.